# How to play drod in windowed mode on OS X?

Tags: macos, deadly-rooms-of-death

Searching on the drod page and its forums I was not able to dig up an information on how to play drod in windowed mode on OS X. Is it possible to always use windowed mode on startup?

Comment: DROD! +1 for nostalgia...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried <kbd>Command + M</kbd>?  That is the shortcut for making a fullscreen app windowed.  Works for every game I've tried.

Comment: +1 for keyboard shortcut. If the game wasn't made to support windowed mode you won't be able to play it in windowed mode on startup, so this is really the closest thing to an answer this question will get.